# React JS: Use environment variables to specify two API urls based on production vs development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, environment-variables

I used create-react-app as the boilerplate for my React app.

I am using fetch to make a request to my local server

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/users")
 .then(function(res){
  return res.json()
})
.then(function(res){
  return res.data
})
```

Eventually when I deploy to heroku I won't be using http://localhost but rather something like https://safe-escarpment-99271.herokuapp.com/.

Is there a way to store the API url in an environment variable

ie. `fetch(API_URL)`

so I can have it on Github when it's deployed but still test locally and not have to change the url back and forth.

I see

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env':{
     'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
     'API_URL': JSON.stringify('http://localhost:8080/bands')
   }
}),
```

on many answers but that doesn't seem to be working for me. When I `console.log(process.env)` the only thing that shows is `NODE_ENV` and `PUBLIC_URL`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
const url = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') 
    ? 'http://localhost:8080/bands/'
    : 'https://<your-app>.herokuapp.com/bands/';
```

On heroku default NODE_ENV=production:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/688

Answer (score 1):

Try using [EnvironmentPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#environmentplugin):

```
new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
    "NODE_ENV",
    "API_URL"
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to prepend a name of every new environmental variable with `REACT_APP_`.
In your case it would be `REACT_APP_API_URL`.

The reason behind it is that create-react-app ignores all custom environmental variables if they don't start with `REACT_APP_` (`NODE_ENV` and `PUBLIC_URL` are exceptions).